# What story has an aging actor cared for by a robotic facsimile of his daughter in her childhood, who is visited by his real adult daughter?

Tags: story-identification, robots, artificial-intelligence

The section of plot I recall involves an older man, a former actor who is suffering from some form of cognitive decline, visited for the first time in years by his adult daughter.  The man lives in a retirement community designed to look like something from an earlier time (I believe the 1950s, but it might be some other era).  He's cared for by an intelligent artificial/robotic companion who is designed to look like his daughter in her childhood, which the adult daughter at first finds unsettling.  The adult daughter and the robot have a private conversation in which the robot reveals that she has plans for her later life, but is content caring for the old actor for now.

Hazier details: The actor believed he was going to perform a famous role (King Lear?  Hamlet?) and the daughter's mother was the one paying for the man's retirement home and for the robot.  I do not recall if this was a short story or merely a portion of a longer work, although it's more likely it's a short story.

Answer (score 0):

The genders are reversed, but ["Today I am Paul" by Martin L Shoemaker](https://clarkesworldmagazine.com/shoemaker_08_15/) has the same premise - an android playing the part of the loved ones of a dementia victim (Mildred).

> Today I am Paul. I activate my chassis extender, giving myself 3.5 centimeters additional height so as to approximate Paul’s size. I change my eye color to R60, G200, B180, the average shade of Paul’s eyes in interior lighting. I adjust my skin tone as well. When I had first emulated Paul, I had regretted that I could not quickly emulate his beard; but Mildred never seems to notice its absence. The Paul in her memory has no beard.

It assumes the appearances of a few other family members throughout the story as well. This includes Mildred's daughter in law, who shows up one day to visit when the android looks like her. She does indeed find it unsettling and they talk.

The android doesn't have any future plans and nobody's an actor, though.